# How to remove bvh data completely using scripts in blender?

Tags: scripting, data-blocks

I'm trying doing bvh retargeting using blender script. After I delete bvh using `bpy.ops.object.delete()`, the bvh data is still in memory, but I have many bvh file to deal with. So I reopen blender file using `bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)`, then some errors occur.

This is the framework of my code:

```
import bpy
import os

def import_bvh(src_path):
    bpy.ops.import_anim.bvh(filepath=src_path, axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')


for i in range(2):
    print("------iterating..", i)
    src_path = ["F:/01_01.bvh", "F:/01_02.bvh"]
    import_bvh(src_path[i])     
    print("import success")
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
    print("do something with bvh")
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="SELECT")
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)
    bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)
    print("end")
```

And this is the console output, any suggestions would help:)

```
------iterating.. 0
        parsing bvh 'F:/01_01.bvh'...   zero length node found: Hips
0.1406
        importing to blender... zero length bone found: Spine1
        zero length bone found: LeftHand
        zero length bone found: RightHand
Done in 0.5342

import success
do something with bvh
read blend: F:\CAPG\mm_lzj\code\retarget_bvh\test_res\test_open_blend.blend
end
------iterating.. 1
        parsing bvh 'F:/01_02.bvh'...   zero length node found: Hips
0.1446
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ProgramFiles\blender-2.78c-windows64\2.78\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\__init__.py", line 140, in execute
    return import_bvh.load(context, report=self.report, **keywords)
  File "E:\ProgramFiles\blender-2.78c-windows64\2.78\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\import_bvh.py", line 669, in load
    use_fps_scale=use_fps_scale,
  File "E:\ProgramFiles\blender-2.78c-windows64\2.78\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\import_bvh.py", line 394, in bvh_node_dict2armature
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)
  File "E:\ProgramFiles\blender-2.78c-windows64\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

Comment: Due to saving and opening a file in your loop with operators, naffs the context for the next iteration. Seriously consider the need  of saving and reopening a file in script like above. Can you undo easily? Could lead to a "whoops  I've deleted everything and saved over the top"  Saving  a timestamped back up with save_as would be my recommendation.

Comment: I'm going to deal with a sequence of bvh files, that's why I use the loop to delete old bvh('01_01.bvh') and import new bvh('01_02.bvh'). So delete all old data is what I actually need, but I don't know how to delete the data while maintain the correct context. Maybe the question is not that clear.

Comment: The import creates a rig object, armature and action. Assuming you want to save only action, use `bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)` and `bpy.data.armatures.remove(rig)` where obj is context object and rig is context object data after import would suffice IMO.

Comment: Pure remove or delete method cannot remove data from memory. After I process 10 bvh files(10/ 2000), blender will crash because of Out-of-Memory.So I try to reopen blend file, but the context isn't correct(I'm new to blender, I don't understand why and not find a way by googling). Do you have any advice that I can process one file each time with no previous memory left in blender?Thanks:-）

Comment: How attached are you to your code above? I wouldn't do it that way, it's prob not the bvh data that's filling your memory and crashing blender, more likely  the undo stack that (AFAIK still) keeps a "snapshot" of each operation.  In [old wip addon](https://github.com/batFINGER/batFINGER-blender-addons/tree/master/mocap_madness) the importer was modified for multi file selection, to import a cmu chapter in one fell swoop. Even on my shitbox machine It didn't crash.

Comment: Or similarly look at using `from io_anim_bvh.import_bvh import read_bvh` to avoid using bvh import operator altogether.